# TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'tuple'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Here in my code i want to compute the variation of Q with respect to the variation of l and d but I am getting an error of TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'tuple' how to fix this issue

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_with_variating_D ():
    l = np.arange(1, 1.5, 0.01)
    d = np.arange(0.005, 0.015, 0.0002)
    zero=np.zeros(50)
    one=np.ones(50)
    Eb1 = 3543.75
    A1 = 1
    A2 = np.pi * (d / 2)
    A3 = np.pi
    F11 = 0
    F21 = 2 * (np.arctan(0.5 / l) * (180 / np.pi)) / 360
    F12 = (d * np.pi * F21)
    F12p = (((4 / l ** 2) + 4) ** 0.5 - 2) * (l / 2)
    F13 = F12p - F12
    F14 = 1 - F12 - F13
    F23 = 0.5
    F24 = 1 - F21 - F23
    F34 = F14 / np.pi
    rho = 0.7
    k = 0.04
    pr = 0.7
    cp = 1005
    myu = 2.4 * 10 ** -5
    alpha = 5.68 * 10 ** -5
    beta = 1 / 500
    Ra = (rho * 9.81 * beta * (500 - 293) * l) / (myu * alpha)
    Nu = 0.68 + (0.67 * Ra ** 0.25) / (1 + (0.429 / pr) ** (9 / 16)) ** (4 / 9)
    h = Nu * k
    J1 = 3543.75 + 0.42 * h * (500 - 295)

    a = np.array([[F12,F13, zero], [A2*F23,-(A2*F23+F13,zero)], [-(4*A2+F12+A2*F23),A2*F23,4*A2]])
    b = np.array([7*(J1-Eb1)/3 +F12*J1+F13*J1,-F13*J1,-F12*J1])
    x = np.linalg.solve(np.moveaxis(a, -1, 0), np.moveaxis(b,-1,0))
    x = x.T
    J2 = -x[0]

    J3 = x[1]
    Eb2 = -x[2]
    qrad = (Eb2 - J2)*(0.8 * A2) / 0.2
    print(Eb2)
    return qrad

plot_with_variating_D()
```

Comment: Please add the complete traceback

Comment: `d` is a range, which means multiple values (i.e. a tuple), what exactly was that you were trying to achieve?

Comment: File "C:/Users/user/pythonn/heat.py", line 52, in <module>
    plot_with_variating_D()
  File "C:/Users/user/pythonn/heat.py", line 42, in plot_with_variating_D
    x = np.linalg.solve(np.moveaxis(a, -1, 0), b)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in solve
  File "C:\Users\user\pythonn\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 385, in solve
    _assert_stacked_2d(a)
  File "C:\Users\user\pythonn\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 207, in _assert_stacked_2d
    'at least two-dimensional' % a.ndim)
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: 1-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional

Comment: i want to compute qrad with respect to new values of D and L

Answer (score 0):

The following line causes it:

```py
    a = np.array([[F12,F13, zero], [A2*F23,-(A2*F23+F13,zero)], [-(4*A2+F12+A2*F23),A2*F23,4*A2]])
```

More specifically: `[A2*F23,-(A2*F23+F13,zero)]` is invalid.

I'm guessing you meant `[A2*F23,-(A2*F23+F13),zero]`